# Connect multiple authentication mechanisms Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a security configuration for my application that authenticates the user via `LDAP`. This works out pretty fine, but now I'd like to add another `AuthenticationProvider` that does some more checks on the user that tries authenticate. So I tried to add a `DbAuthenticationProvider` that (for testing purposes) always denies the access.  So when I am trying to log in with my domain account (that works for the `activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`) I am not able to access the page because the second provider fails the authentication.

To accomplish this goal, I used the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String AD_URL;

    @Autowired
    UserRoleComponent userRoleComponent;

    @Autowired
    DbAuthenticationProvider dbAuthenticationProvider;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.logger.info("Verify logging level");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and().httpBasic().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.authenticationProvider(dbAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(), dbAuthenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN,
                AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

And this is my `DbAuthenticationProvider`:

```
@Component
public class DbAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        auth.setAuthenticated(false);
        this.logger.info("Got initialized");
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Sadly I am able to log in (the access is not denied as I expected it to be). Did I miss out something?

Comment: just as a hint: you may want to look up redhats keycloak, which could fullfill your requirements and more out of the box and has a great spring integration.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Authentication providers are run in order if any one of them pass the request is allowed. So in your case ldap provider processes the authentication and request is authenticated. Is this not the behavior ?

Comment: @Veeram My desired behaviour was to authenticate via ldap and db in this step. So check Authentication via ldap provider and database provider (if user is in database & authentication via ldap worked, then authenticate the request, if not - don't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Won't use more than one `AuthenticationProvider` to authenticate the request, so the first (in the `ArrayList`) `AuthenticationProvider` that support the `Authentication` object and successfully authenticate the request will be the only one used. in your case it's `activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

instead of using `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`, you can use a custom AuthenticationProvider that delegates to LDAP and do additional checks:

```
    CustomerAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
        privtae ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider  delegate; // add additional methods to initialize delegate during your configuration

          @Override
         public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws 
             AuthenticationException {
            Authentication  authentication= delegate.authenticate(auth);
            additionalChecks(authentication);
           return auth;
           }


          @Override
          public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
          }

        public void additionalCheck(Authentication authentication){
               // throw AuthenticationException when it's not allowed
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's a great approach, sadly the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` is a final class, can I somehow workaround that?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this part "add additional methods to initialize delegate during your configuration"? Your approach is the best one

Answer (score 4):

That is not how an `AuthenticationProvider` works, only one will be consulted for authentication. Apparently you want to combine some information from LDAP and from the DB. For this you can configure a custom [`UserDetailsContextMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/UserDetailsContextMapper.html) and/or [`GrantedAuthoritiesMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/GrantedAuthoritiesMapper.html). The default implementation will use the information from LDAP to contruct the `UserDetails` and its `GrantedAuthorities` however you could implement a strategy which consults the database.

Another solution is to use the `LdapUserDetailsService` which allows you to use the regular `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. The name is misleading as it actually requires an `UserDetailsService`. This `AuthenticationProvider` does additional checks using the [`UserDetailsChecker`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsChecker.html), which by default checks some of the properties on the `UserDetails`, but can be extended with your additional checks.

**NOTE:** The `LdapUserDetailsService` uses plain LDAP so I don't know if that is applicable to the slightly different Active Directory approach!

A final solution could be to create a `DelegatingAuthenticationProvider` which extends from `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` so that you can reuse the logic in there to utilize the `UserDetailsChecker`. The `retrieveUser` method would then delegate to the actual `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` to do the authentication.

**NOTE:** Instead of extending the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` you could of course also create a simpler version yourself.

All in all I suspect that creating a customized `UserDetailsContextMapper` would be the easiest and when not found in DB throw an `UsernameNotFoundException`. This way the normal flow still applies and you can reuse most of the existing infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

As sample work around  on multiple authentication mechanism :
find the code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("container")
public class CustomWebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderDB;

@Override
@Order(1)
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Order(2)
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderDB);
}

@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/scripts/**","/styles/**","/images/**","/error/**");
  }

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            //To change body of generated methods,
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        }
            })
            .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailure(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                        }
            })
            .loginProcessingUrl("/access/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/access/logout")                
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response, 
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
                }
            })
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .csrf()//Disabled CSRF protection
            .disable();
    }
}
```

configured two authentication providers in  Spring Security

```
 <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationProvider " />
      <security:authentication-provider ref="dbAuthenticationProvider" />
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

configuration which helps configure multiple authentication providers in java config.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    auth.authenticationProvider(DBauthenticationProvider);
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class XSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LDAPAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private DBAuthenticationProvider dbauthenticationProvider;

    @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
             .antMatchers("/scripts/**","/styles/**","/images/**","/error/**");
      }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        auth.authenticationProvider(dbauthenticationProvider);

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")         
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .usernameParameter("user")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .failureUrl("/index?failed=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/test",true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
         .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                  .logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout=true").permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error");
    }

}
```

objectPostProcessor inside the configure method need AuthenticationManagerBuilder to actually build the object before we can access and change the order of the providers

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
           .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
      auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(this.dataSource));

      auth.objectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<Object>() {
        @Override
        public <O> O postProcess(O object) {
            ProviderManager providerManager = (ProviderManager) object;
            Collections.swap(providerManager.getProviders(), 0, 1);
            return object;
        }
    });
}
```