# Multiple Authentification using jdbcAuthentification and AD authentification

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I need your help again. I need to authentificate to my app by JDBC or AD, but it must work all. For example, when I try to authentificate using JDBC user, my program has to connect with user from database, but when i put there AD login, it has to connect with AD user.

Here is my code, but when I have below order(1) code to connect to JDBC , I Can connect ONLY with JDBC and when i have there code to create authentificationProvider i can sign in just when i am using AD login.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource primaryDataSource;

    // @Autowired
    // private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    // @Autowired
    // private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderAD;

    @Value("${security.authentication.provider}")
    private String authProvider;

    @Value("${ad.domain:#{null}}")
    private String adDomain;

    // TODO shift system like configuration into java, and no system like
    // configuration make it optional
    @Value("${ad.url:#{null}}")
    private String adUrl;

    @Override
    @Order(1)
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   RecursiveAdProvider adProvider = new RecursiveAdProvider(adDomain, adUrl);
    adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }

    @Order(2)
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(primaryDataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, authority from user_authority JOIN authorities ON user_authority.authority_id = authorities.id where username=?")
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: do both mechanisms have to work simultaneously or depending on the environment one or the other?

Comment: Our system has some users from database and some users from AD and they are using just one login formular.. When login using databse does not work because that user does not exists in database we need to use active directory user ....

Comment: @dom do you know any resolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect multiple authentication mechanisms Spring Boot Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54345243/connect-multiple-authentication-mechanisms-spring-boot-security)